# input.wav will copy to output.wav but will not multiply the input file by the factor

Tags: c, cs50

This program is supposed to take the input file and copy it to the output file and then go by 2 bit samples and change the volume of the input file and save the updated version in the output file. The input file copies into output.wav but won't change the volume of it. I know I'm fairly on track but can't figure out why it won't work correctly. This also passes check50 somehow but when I compile and run it myself it doesn't do what it's supposed to do.

```
    // Modifies the volume of an audio file

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Number of bytes in .wav header
const int HEADER_SIZE = 44;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check command-line arguments
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./volume input.wav output.wav factor\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open files and determine scaling factor
    FILE *input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (input == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *output = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    if (output == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    float factor = atof(argv[3]);

    // TODO: Copy header from input file to output file
    uint8_t header[HEADER_SIZE];
    fread(header, HEADER_SIZE, 1, input);
    fwrite(header, HEADER_SIZE, 1, output);

    // TODO: Read samples from input file and write updated data to output file
    int16_t buffer;
    while(fread(&buffer, sizeof(int16_t), 1, input))
    {
        buffer = buffer * factor;
        fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(int16_t), 1, output);
    }
    // Close files
    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `factor`?

Comment: @Retired Ninja. the value of factor is argv[3] so its whatever the user inputs as the 4th command line argument.

Comment: I have tried with 2.0 and 0.5 and neither worked.

Comment: You multiple a signed value.  Is it ok that the value goes negative on overflow and positive on underflow?  Your program, for me, does exactly as indicated.  It starts at byte 44 and scales the value.  I don't know if that is a valid algorithm.  You can use xxd to convert the binary wav to hex, then diff input and output hex files to see what changed.

Comment: "it won't work correctly." or "doesn't do what it's supposed to do" means nothing to us, so vote to close as lacking debug data (your file), clarity of what the problem is and ability to reproduce the issue.  Because I was curious about the magic value of 44, however, I did write you an answer that might help you (or not).

Answer (score 0):

http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html tells you that a wave file is a sequence of chunks.  Each chunk starts with a 4 byte chunk id (chkid) followed by a 4 byte (little-endian) chunk size (cksize).  There are different types of chunks, so I suggest you read chkid and cksize, then figure out out if you want process that chunk.  For scaling you only want process the samples of ckkid = "data" and it assumes your file is wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM, i.e. PCM encoded.

You didn't tell us much about your input file so I grabbed the first file from https://samplelib.com/sample-wav.html.  It consist of 3 chunks "RIFF", "fmt " and "data".  The data samples in this file start at byte 44.  This file has wBitsPerSample = 16 or 2 bytes per sample.  You said "2 bit samples" but I assume you meant byte.  When I run your program over this file with factor = 2 the first sample is 0xf872 which is -1934, and the corresponding output file sample is 0xf0e4 = -3868.  When I visually compare the input and output files in a wave editor (in my case mhwaveedit) it looks scaled.

As I mentioned, `buffer * factor` may under or overflow, and in audio you usually clip it rather than wrap.  Here is way to accomplish this:

```
printf("buffer = %d", buffer);
if(factor * buffer > INT16_MAX)
  buffer = INT16_MAX;
else if(factor * buffer < INT16_MIN)
  buffer = INT16_MIN;
else
  buffer *= factor;
printf(" => %d\n", buffer);
```

And when I now run your program it clips:

```
$ ./clipping input.wav output.wav 2|egrep -- '-32768|32767' | head -1
buffer = 16661 => 32767
```

where that sample previously would overflow:

```
$ ./scaling input.wav output.wav 2|grep 16661 | head -1
buffer = 16661 => -32214
```